# Detach a view from layout and make it full-screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to expand a VideoView to full screen and horizontal mode whenever a 'full-screen' button is clicked, but I cannot find a way to expand the view completely over the whole screen. I have a toolbar and a tabbed layout I can't find a way to bypass both of them and apply the view *over* them. Anybody has ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Without code I am not sure of your layout but, translate your TabLayout out of the way and go to 'immersive' mode to hide all system bars. You can use the following method:

```
private void hideSystemUI() {

    // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the content
    // doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
    getWindow().getDecorView().setFitsSystemWindows(false);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}
```

To come out of immersive mode, just use the following method:

```
private void showSystemUI() {

    getWindow().getDecorView().setFitsSystemWindows(true);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I am targeting API 15, all of these options are for API 16, I assume that's why nothing happened when I called the functions. What do you mean by 'translate' the layout out of the way -- hide it? I am manipulating the current tab through a Fragment class, I don't think it has any knowledge of the tab layout, or that I even have a toolbar with a drawer, and such...

Comment: If you had something like a `CoordinatorLayout`, then a `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar` and `TabLayouts` as children, you could use `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` to hide them all on scrolling